# Run tweaks in iOS 8 Simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, jailbreak

There is a doc about running tweaks in iOS 7 Simulator.
http://sharedinstance.net/2013/10/running-tweaks-in-simulator/

And it seams to be out dated and does not work with iOS 8 Simulator.
Particularly, builded tweak does not inject into SpringBoard app.
Are there any updated guides?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the same it worked for me in ios 8.3